# How to retrieve dynamically generated web elements?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I fetch the website using Jsoup. Here is the link to the web:

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=restaurants&find_loc=westmont%2C+il&ns=1&ls=43131f934bb3adf3#find_loc=Hinsdale,+IL&l=p:IL:Hinsdale::&sortby=rating&unfold=1

Now I'm trying to extract the number of sub-pages on the web. For example the numbers next to "Go to Page" as shown in the picture below:[image]

Unfortunately either 'view source' in the browser or Jsoup is not able to see these elements. I guess this content is embedded dynamically into the web. If so what is the best way to access dynamically generated web? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the website that use AJAX/JS Libraries technique to generate content, you may want to use HTMLUnit instead (HTMLUnit can simulate Javascript events). JSoup is only for static HTML, or things that you could receive via viewsource.